# How can I be updated of an attribute change in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a template that subscribes to a document. Everything works fine in the DOM and Blaze updates as soon as an attribute used in the template helpers is changed.

I also have some custom logic that doesn't appears in the DOM and depends on the document attributes. How can I call a function to change that logic when an attribute is updated?

I'm looking for something like `this.data.attr.onChanged` where `this` would refer to the template and `this.data` is the data send to the template, as usual; or a Meteor function that is rerun on change where I could put my callback in.

I hoped that template.onRendered would be recalled, but that's not the case.

I've read a lot about reactive variables, but could not find how they could be useful here.

[edit] the change is coming from the server that is communicating with another service

I've tried `Tracker.autorun` like this:

```
Template.editItem.onRendered(function() {
  var self = this;
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    console.log("tracker", self.data.item.socketId);
  });
});
```

And the corresponding route is:

```
Router.route('editItem', {
  path: '/edit/:_id',
  waitOn: function () {
    var sub = Meteor.subscribe('item', this.params._id);
    return [sub]; 
  },
  data: function () {
    return {item: Items.findOne(this.params._id)};
  },
  action: function () {
    if (this.ready())
      this.render();
  }
});
```

At some point, the property `socketId` gets removed from the corresponding document by the server and I'm sure of that since I've checked in the shell, but the tracker doesn't rerun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Template.currentData().item.socketId` instead of `self.data.item.socketId`, this will give you reactivity.

And in templates generally, use `self.autorun` instead of `Tracker.autorun` (unlike `Tracker.autorun`, this will ensure that the autorun is stopped when the template is destroyed). Likewise, if you want to subscribe in a template, use `self.subscribe` instead of `Meteor.subscribe`.

Code to see if Template.currentData() works for you:

```
Template.editItem.onRendered(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function () {
    console.log("tracker", Template.currentData().item.socketId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep `Template.currentData()` is what I was missing to make the data reactive. Thanks for saving me from creating a reactive variable that gets updated from the helpers that would need to be called by an hidden element..!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got you right, you just want to observe your html inputs and apply the new value to your helper method(s) on change?!

If so, you could use session variables to store your temporary UI state:

```
// observe your input
Template.yourTemplate.events({
  "change #inputA": function (event) {
    if(event.target.value != "") {
      Session.set("valueA", event.target.value);
    }
  }
}

// apply the changed value on your helper function
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({

  getSomeData: function() {
    var a = Session.get("valueA");
    // do something with a ..
  }
}
```

In meteor's official [todo app tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/temporary-ui-state) this concept is also used.

Comment: The change is coming from the server. Sorry I should have been clearer at first. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to re-run something which is not part of DOM/helper, you can use `Tracker.autorun`. According to meteor docs, Run a function now and rerun it later whenever its dependencies change.

[here's the docs link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)

Comment: Yeah I had tried that (I updated the question with more info) but that hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the subscription into `Tracker.autorun`

```
Template.editItem.onRendered(function() {
    var self = this;
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('item', this.params._id);
        console.log("tracker", self.data.item.socketId);
    });
});
```

Of course you can't use `this.params` there so you can store this as a Session variable

Comment: OK, what if you, instead of passing data in the route methods, you pass it into template helpers, which are definitely reactive.

Comment: Yes the template helpers are perfectly reactive as excepted, but it doesn't feel right to put there code that is not specifically attached to the DOM rendering, and I can't find how to pass data from onCreated/onRendered to the helpers...
I could write my variable to the DOM with the helpers that get correctly updated and regularly check the value from the DOM element, but that feels terribly wrong